# Adding a constraint to a PFQuery on a PFRelation with objects that have already been gotten

Tags: swift, parse-platform

For some background, I am learning from [the following Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319972/how-to-get-query-wherekeykey-containedin-array-to-work-with-relation-query) question that I asked regarding creating the this code.

I was playing around with different combinations of `whereKey`s and queries, and I found a solution that seems to be working. I'm not really sure if this is the correct or most efficient way to handle a constraint on a query based on a relation, and any help improving or optimizing the code would be appreciated.

```
 let query: PFQuery
 let isNormalQuery = false
 response = objects as! [PFObject]
 var responseObjectIds = [String]()
 for x in response{
     responseObjectIds.append(x.objectId!)
 }
let query2 = PFQuery(className: query.parseClassName)
query2.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: responseObjectIds)
query = PFQuery(className: query.parseClassName)
query.whereKey("objectId", doesNotMatchKey: "objectId", inQuery: query2)
// query2 is then used to fetch objects from the Parse server
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We can help you with improving your code, but explaining is off-topic here. Could you rephrase your question to conform with our [on-topic help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I have no experience with parse.com, but your code is unclear to me. `objects` and `query3` are nowhere defined. `query` and `query2` are assigned but nowhere used.